# How can I change the description of a existing changelist in command line?

Tags: perforce

The command "p4 change" prompts a editor and needs a form. But I want to do this in command line.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you don't want to do this via command-line, you can edit a changelist description in P4V. Open the changelist (right-click, "View Changelist"), and there's an "Edit" button at the bottom which makes the Description field editable, allowing you to fix a typo or confusing description for a changelist.

Comment: It says command-line for a reason :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's always the `-i` command:

> Read a changelist description from standard input. Input must be in the same format used by the p4 change form.

As Bryan points out in his comment the best approach is probably to run `change -o`, redirect the output to a file, process the file with other shell commands, and then send that file back to the server with `change -i`.

[Source](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/change.html#1040665)

But you can always change the description when you submit:

> p4 submit -d "description"

This only works on the default change list.

[Source](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/submit.html)

Comment: To expand on the use of 'change -i': generally the technique is to run 'change -o', redirect the output to a file, process the file with other shell commands (sed, awk, etc.), then send that file back to the server with 'change -i'. This is a common Perforce scripting technique. If you're going to be doing a lot of shell scripting, consider installing and using one of the Perforce scripting API interfaces, such as the Ruby, Perl, or Python APIs.

Comment: Your second example is incorrect - you cannot use -c and -d together. 'p4 submit -d "something"' will submit the default changelist with the supplied description

Answer (score 27):

Use the following command:

> p4 change -u CL_number

For details, please visit [this page](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/change.html).

Comment: Per the linked documentation, this applies to changing an _already submitted_ changelist.

Comment: Looks like the documentation is wrong there. For me, it worked on a shelved changelist.

Answer (score 11):

This command line worked for me:

```
p4 --field Description="New CL description here" change -o *changelist_number* | p4 change -i
```

Comment: --field is civilization.

Comment: It works for the Pending changelist and not for the Submitted changelist