# How to change the p4 submit description

Tags: perforce

I am new to Perforce. Here's the problem:

```
$ p4 submit
Change 9 created with 1 open file(s)
Submitting change 9.
Locking 1 files ...
Submit validation failed -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 9'.
```

The problem is that the description that I entered into the submit form was bad. How do I change it?

I checked the docs for p4 submit, and didn't understand what -i does. Maybe that's what I need.
I tried:

```
$ p4 submit -i "Better description" -c 9 filename
```

and got:

```
Usage: submit [ -i -s -r ] [ -c changelist# ] [file]
Missing/wrong number of arguments
```

Comment: You should be able to change the commit message as described [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634097/how-can-i-change-the-description-of-a-existing-changelist-in-command-line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a pending changelist, and since it doesn't sound like you need to do this from a script, just do:

```
p4 change 9
```

This will bring up the changelist form in an editor so you can edit it.  Make the edits, save the file, then exit the editor.  Then do:

```
p4 submit -c 9
```

You may already know this, but the "validation failed" message means that your Perforce admin has some kind of custom trigger set up that blocked the submit -- the trigger could be doing literally anything, so if it keeps failing you may need to check with your admin to see what you're supposed to be doing (and whether the trigger is behaving correctly).

If you were editing the changelist form from a script you would use the "-i" flag as follows:

```
p4 change -o 9 | sed -e "s/magic/regex/" | p4 change -i
p4 submit -c 9
```

but obviously as an end user it's easier to just do "p4 change 9" and use the editor than to write a shell script to edit the description for you.

With a newer Perforce server you can specify the description during submit with:

```
p4 submit -d "Better description"
```

but since the "-d" flag isn't listed in your usage message I'm guessing you're using an old version.

Answer (score 12):

Even if the changelist is already submitted you can change the description with

```
p4 change -u 9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the best and the most concise answer!

Comment: Thanks is it ```p4 change -u CL_number <new_description>``` ?

Comment: The new description is not a command line parameter but part of the changelist description (see [here](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/change.html)).

Answer (score 4):

In the "History" tab, right click on your entry, "view changelist", then "edit", modify your description and  "ok".